# Monotouch - fast app switching

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios

How is the above implemented in MT? How do I allow the app to open back up to the screen it was last seen in?

w://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is compile your application with the SDK 4.0. The new SDK automatically enables fast app switching, there's nothing you need to do from a code standpoint.

Comment: hmmm... doesnt seem to work for me - switching back shows the loading screen again :s

Comment: are you running the application against the simulator running version 4.0? The simulator can run both 4 and 3.2, and 3.2 doesn't support fast app switch.

To change that, open the simulator, go to Hardware->Version.

Comment: hmmmm, seems to work on the device now... tres strange... cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement Eduardo's answer, you need to compile using the 4.0 SDK, but make sure that in the iPhone Build tab on your project properties you explicitly set the version to 4.0 (chances are, it is still 3.1 from the previous version).